# /etc/update-motd.d/98-fsck-at-reboot exited with return code 1

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I created a new user using adduser

```
adduser test 
adduser test sudo
```

but on login I get the following error

```
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/98-fsck-at-reboot exited with return code 1
Unable to cd to '/home/test
```

What could be issue here

Answer (score 0):

using adduser did not create a home directory for the user. So it looks like that the user did not have a home directory. And login without a home directory may fail.